# How to check in each(), the current div has a particular class or not

Tags: jquery

I have to check if the div has class='completed', then add Hello. if not do nothing.
But the code I've written is adding Hello even if the div doesn't have class='completed' in it.

[jssfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/priyaa2002/qh4xc/3/)
    
        
            1
            2
            3

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $( '#bar > div' ).each(function() { 
      if(($('.complete').length > 0)){
           var txt = $(this).find('.step-number').empty();
                     $(this).find('.step-number').after('<span class="hello">Hello</span>');
      }
  });
});
```

Comment: Why don't you just put the class into the selector: `$('#bar > div.complete')`?

Answer (score 1):

Simply use [hasClass](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/) :

> Determine whether any of the matched elements are assigned the given
>   class

Answer (score 1):

Just replace this code

```
if($('.complete').length > 0){
```

with this

```
if($(this).hasClass('complete')){
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/qh4xc/4/)

Actually, in your code

```
$('.complete').length
```

always returns the value `2`, since you have two elements with that class, thus `$('.complete').length` is always greater than 0. Hence, it is adding `Hello` even if the div doesn't have class='completed' in it.

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery's `hasClass("class-name")`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $( '#bar > div' ).each(function() { 
      if(($(this).hasClass('complete'))){
           var txt = $(this).find('.step-number').empty();
                     $(this).find('.step-number').after('<span class="hello">Hello</span>');
      }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `hasClass`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $( '#bar > div' ).each(function() { 
     if($(this).hasClass('complete')){
           var txt = $(this).find('.step-number').empty();
                     $(this).find('.step-number').after('<span  class="hello">Hello</span>');
      }
  });
});
```

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/qh4xc/5/)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [hasClass](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/) for this purpose.

> Description: Determine whether any of the matched elements are
>   assigned the given class.

Example: `<div id="mydiv" class="foo bar"></div>`

The .hasClass() method will return true if the class is assigned to an element, even if other classes also are. For example, given the HTML above, the following will return true:

`$('#mydiv').hasClass('foo')`

So in your code you should use `if($(this).hasClass('complete'))`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also specify `complete` in the selector as:

```
 $( '#bar > div.complete' ).each(function() { 
      var txt = $(this).find('.step-number').empty();
      $(this).find('.step-number').after('<span class="hello">Hello</span>');
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need the `.each`, you can use the [`:has()`](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) selector.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#bar > div:has(.completed)')
      .find('.step-number')
      .empty()
      .after('<span class="hello">Hello</span>');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `if(($('.complete').length > 0))` you are not checking if the particular div has the class `.complete`, but just selecting all elements with `.complete`.

You can change the loop to:
`$( '#bar > div' ).each(function(index, div) {...}`
and than just check with `.hasClass()` if the div has the desired class.